# Installing PHP-CURL using apt-get

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I installed curl using synaptic package manager on my Ubuntu machine. However it didn't installed with ssl enabled. When I do `curl-config --protocols`, it does not show HTTPS.

I want to install curl with ssl enabled. If I do it manually by downloading curl and then compiling it with `--with-ssl` flag and then recompiling my PHP with `-with-curl`, this is tedious and also i have many packages which are installed in PHP, so i have to re-install them back again.

I am looking for some way if i could supply the `--with-ssl=/usr/lib/ssl` flag with apt-get or synaptic package manager. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need to uninstall your existing package and install the `curl-ssl` package like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove curl
sudo apt-get install curl-ssl
```

Depending on what else you have installed, you may also need `libcurl`.

Comment: It will probably use libcurl.